# Converting between 24 hour and 12 hour time

Tags: java, time

I am a beginner in Java programming, and I am trying to convert between 12-hour and 24-hour times using if statements, for loops and while loops only. Please refer to my attempt below. I have so far tried converting from 12-hour to 24-hour time. You may find the code ridiculously incorrect, but I just can't figure out where I have gone wrong. Please help me with the code.. I'll appreciate it!

Attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TimeConverter {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a time ([h]h:mm [am|pm]):");
    String input = s.nextLine();
    if(input.charAt(input.length()-1)== "m")
       String x = input.substring(0,2);
       int TwentyFour = int x + 12;
       System.out.println(TwentyFour);


   }
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: In what way(s) is it wrong?

Comment: I haven't quite tried looking at your logic but what are you trying to do here 

int TwentyFour = int x + 12;

Here x is a String .... try Integer.parseInt for String to Integer conversion

Answer (score 0):

Why are you testing for "m" in the if statement. Isn't AM and PM going to both have that "m". I would say testing for "a" or "p" in the if statement and then handling the opposite in an else statement.

Another thing is that the user could enter capital or lower case letters so you need to handle that too. One easy way to do that is to first store the letter you want to test and use the toUpperCase method of the String class.

Also, I'm assuming you want the user to be able to input in variable formats. E.g. 9:00 PM or 09:00 PM. to handle these scenarios, I would check at which index the ":" is at. To do this you can use the indexOf() method of the string class.

This will help you with the first scenario, but you can implement the second.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TimeConverter {
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a time ([h]h:mm [am|pm]):");
String input = s.nextLine();

String whichHalf;
whichHalf = input.charAt(input.length()-1);
whichHalf.toUpperCase();
if(whichHalf== "P")//it's PM
   String x = input.substring(0,2);
   int TwentyFour = int x + 12;
   System.out.println(TwentyFour);
}
else //it's AM
{
    //don't convert just print
}

}
```

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the late response. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code is vastly incorrect.  I remember those days when I too was a beginner learning Java.

Here is a corrected version of the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TimeConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a time ([h]h:mm [am|pm]):");
        String input = s.next();

        char whichHalf = input.charAt(input.length() - 2);
        whichHalf = whichHalf.toUpperCase();

        if(whichHalf == 'P'){
            String x = input.substring(0, 2);
            double twentyFour = Double.parseDouble(x) + 12;
            System.out.println(twentyFour);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the pitfalls you may want to watch out for in the future:

-you cannot convert a String directly to an int.  You must use a method such as Double.parseDouble()

-The charAt() method returns a character, not a String, so it cannot be compared to "M", but it can be compared to 'M' (notice the apostrophes instead of quotes, denoting a char instead of a String).  You also checked the wrong letter.  You should have checked the first letter of "AM" or "PM".

-Lastly, I changed "nextLine()" to "next()" because I find that "nextLine()" acts strangely.  This is a personal style that you do not have to follow.

That's it, I hope I helped!  Good luck with your program and your coding career.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late response. Thanks a lot for your help :)